# MP3 + JPG of same name

Tags: batch-file, cmd, ffmpeg

For every mp3 file in my folder I have a certain jpg file with the same name, what I'm trying to achieve with cmd is making that name into one variable name without the file extension

This is my code using only a mp3 name

```
for %%a in ("*.mp3") do ffmpeg -i "%%a.mp3" -loop 1 -i Cover.jpg -c:v libx264 -tune stillimage -c:a aac -strict experimental -b:a 320k -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf scale=3000:3000 -shortest "%%~na.mp4"
```

Comment: why `"%%a.mp3"`? This would result in two extensions. You use `"%%~na.mp4"` - why not doing the same trick to the `.jpg`?

Comment: You haven't asked a question.

Answer (score 1):

I thought the `.jpg` name must match the `.mp3` name. Why is `Cover.jpg` hardcoded?

```
for %%a in ("*.mp3") do ffmpeg -i "%%~na.mp3" -loop 1 ^
    -i "%%~na.jpg" ^
    -c:v libx264 -tune stillimage -c:a aac ^
    -strict experimental -b:a 320k -pix_fmt yuv420p ^
    -vf scale=3000:3000 ^
    -shortest "%%~na.mp4"
```